# Prove that $C$ is a basis in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove if $B = \{ \vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3 \}$ is a basis in $\mathbb{R^3}$, then so is $C = \{ v_1+v_2, v_2+v_3, v_1+v_3 \}$.

I've already proven that $C$ is linearly independent. How do I prove that $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ and that it spans it? It seems that I can write $C$ as a combination $x(v_1+v_2)+y(v_2+v_3)+z(v_1+v_3)$, where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: There is no need to "prove" that $C$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$. If $v$ and $w$ are elements of $\Bbb R^3$, then by the definition of addition it holds that $v + w$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: How did you prove that $C$ is linearly independent? If this proof was correct, then there's probably a way to leverage your proof so that we also show that the vectors span $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You proved that $\dim \operatorname{span} C = 3$. But $C$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ has dimension $3$. Hence...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. There is a theorem, Steinitz exchange lemma, that states that if $C$ is linearly independent with $n$ elements, then it is also a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is what you want, isn't it?